# symfony2 twig variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to change the href attribute of a link of css. The problem is it does not show the varible `{{app.user.tema}}` the problem of the quotes.

```
{% block tema%}
   {% if app.user.tema %}
     <link id = "hojaestilo" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css" href = "{{asset ('bundles / appapp / css / themes / {{app.user.tema}} / jquery-wijmo.css')}} "media =" screen ">
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The error I get is:

> Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" ("punctuation" expected with value `","`) in appappBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining the variable and the string with ~ may work:

```
 <link id = "hojaestilo" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{{asset ('bundles/appapp/css/themes/' ~ app.user.tema ~ '/jquery-wijmo.css')}}" media ="screen">
```